# Problem installing Docker Ubuntu, step related to command "pub" (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**My ubuntu version:**
No LSB modules are available./
Distributor ID: Ubuntu /
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS /
Release:    18.04 /
Codename:   bionic

To install Docker Engine - Community, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Ubuntu versions:

Disco 19.04
Cosmic 18.10
**Bionic 18.04 (LTS)** (Mine)
Xenial 16.04 (LTS)

**Steps I followed:**

Uninstall old versions

`$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

Update the apt package index:

`$ sudo apt-get update #HasErrors (2)`

```
(1) Err:14 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian $distribution Release                                                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 3.124. ..........]
------------------------------------------------
(2) E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian $distribution Release' does not have a Release file.
```

**In consequence:** When I get to step 3 in the webpage: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

```
$ sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]
```

I get this error:

```
Command 'pub' not found, did you mean:

  command 'hub' from snap hub (v2.13.0)
  command 'dub' from snap dub (1.15.0)
  command 'pcb' from deb pcb-gtk
  command 'pcb' from deb pcb-lesstif
  command 'pua' from deb pglistener
  command 'pudb' from deb python-pudb
  command 'puf' from deb puf
  command 'pdb' from deb python
  command 'dub' from deb dub
  command 'publ' from deb atfs

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

**I just want to install Docker for Ubuntu and i am a little stuck here**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing from the repository, why don't you try doing it directly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

If this works, you will notice it only works with `sudo` the workaround for this issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/docker-without-sudo.md)

Let me know if this doesn't work! I'm also quite confused as to why your errors include RabbitMQ when you are trying to install docker on ubuntu?

Comment: I Tried that one too, but the error is born in the **$ sudo apt-get update** command, here are the errors: 

 (1) Err:14 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian $distribution Release

404 Not Found [IP: 3.124. ..........]
(2) E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian $distribution Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: the problem you have is you tried to install rabbitmq, and that didn't work. And so when you do `sudo apt update` it tries to install that repo, and you didn't clean up the mess that was caused. Either look into how to clean up, or then complete the installation using [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) link

Comment: As you told me, the issue was directly related to rabbitmq. Docker works fine now. 
Thank you for your help!